# How to change voice on iMovie iPad?

Tags: ipad, audio, imovie

I want to change the voice of my clip. For example, I want to make the voice more deep, or high, more masculine, or feminine. How can I do that on iMovie on iPad?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the voice clip using GarageBand.

Comment: How? This doesn't really give the OP much to work with.